# EF composite Foreign key getting error

Tags: entity-framework

I have the below model

```
public class DeptContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasKey(t => t.EmpId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasKey(t => t.DeptId);
    }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public int DivNo { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public int DivisionNo { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create a composite primary key with `DeptId` and `DivNo` as keys in department.

I've added the following code in the OnModelCreating()

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasKey(t => new {t.DeptId, t.DivNo});
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasRequired(t => t.Department)
                      .WithMany(g=>g.Employees)
                      .HasForeignKey(t => new { t.DepartmentId, t.DivisionNo });
```

I used Migrations and following is the code which i got (only the UP())

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Departments", "DeptId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Departments", new[] { "DeptId" });
AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Departments", new[] { "DeptId", "DivNo" });
AddForeignKey("dbo.Employees", new[] { "DivisionNo", "DepartmentId" }, "dbo.Departments", new[] { "DeptId", "DivNo" }, cascadeDelete: true);
CreateIndex("dbo.Employees", new[] { "DivisionNo", "DepartmentId" });
```

Now the question is when I added the composite foreign key in the model builder I'm not getting the `DropForeignKey` statement in `up()` of the existing foreign key getting the error as

> The constraint 'PK_dbo.Departments' is being referenced by table 'Employees', foreign key constraint 'FK_dbo.Employees_dbo.Departments_DepartmentId'.

Is this the code issue or the ef issue. If it is mine please let me know where I'm wrong.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like a bug in migrations. There's no way how your code could mess this up.

But my strong advice would be not to use a composite primary key, *especially* not when one of its fields has a meaning in the business domain (which `DivisionNo` has?). Composite primary keys add more complexity than you can ever gain by introducing them. They should only occur in junction tables.

It looks like you should introduce a class/table `Division`. I don't see how `DivNo` can add to the identification of a `Department`. If you've got two departments with the same `DeptId` and different `DivNo`s, would that be totally different departments?